# Enable KDE Plasma 5 after installing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kde, plasma

I have installed the Neon5 plasma framework on my Ubuntu 14.04 but I can't enable it
I tried to look at Unity Tweak Tool and CompizConfig but didn't find anything
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Before you log in into KDE, click on the blue down-arrow, and select the Project Neon 5 option. You'll then boot into KDE Plasma 5.

Comment: Looks like Bayar also needs to log out of Unity first.

Comment: @int_ua: Maybe not. It could be that he just has those two programs installed (considering most websites refer to them for use in Ubuntu) but not the Unity DE, which would mean the two programs have absolutely no impact on KDE (or anything, for that matter)

Comment: KDE Plasma 5 is the new version of KDE. Since Bayar mentions Unity Tweak Tool and CCSM I'm almost sure he is using Unity. Maybe with autologin even.